# Java incorrect output when running application

Tags: java, intellij-idea, runtime

I have an exercise to do from this book I am learning from
The exercise is the following:

Create a class called Employee that includes three instance variables—a first
name (type String), a last name (type String) and a monthly salary (double). Provide a constructor
that initializes the three instance variables. Provide a set and a get method for each instance variable. If
the monthly salary is not positive, do not set its value. Write a test application named EmployeeTest
that demonstrates class Employee’s capabilities. Create two Employee objects and display each object’s
yearly salary. Then give each Employee a 10% raise and display each Employee’s yearly salary again.

Code for the superclass:

```
public class employee {

private String firstname;
private String lastname;
private double salary;
private double raise;

public employee(String firstname1, String lastname1, double salary1)
{
    firstname = firstname1;
    lastname = lastname1;
    salary = salary1;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname1)
{
    firstname = firstname1;
}

public String getFirstname()
{
    return firstname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname1)
{
    lastname = lastname1;
}

public String getLastname()
{
    return  lastname;
}

public void setSalary(double salary1)
{
    if(salary1 > 0)
    salary = salary1;
}

public double getSalary()
{
    return salary;
}


public double getRaise()
{
    salary = (salary * 10)/100 + salary;
    return salary;
}
```

}

Code for the subclass:

```
public class employeeTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    employee emp1 = new employee(null, null, 0);
    employee emp2 = new employee(null, null, 0);

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter the 1 employee first name: ");
    String fn1;
    fn1 = input.nextLine();
    emp1.setFirstname(fn1);
    emp1.getFirstname();


    System.out.println("Enter the 1 employee last name: ");
    String ln1;
    ln1 = input.nextLine();
    emp1.setLastname(ln1);
    emp1.getLastname();


    System.out.println("Enter the 1 employee yearly salary: ");
    double sl1;
    sl1 = input.nextDouble();
    emp1.setSalary(sl1);
    emp1.getSalary();
    System.out.printf("%s %s's yearly salary before the raise is %.2f\n", emp1.getFirstname(), emp1.getLastname(), emp1.getSalary());
    System.out.println();






    System.out.println("Enter the 2 employee first name:\n");
    String fn2;
    fn2 = input.nextLine();
    emp2.setFirstname(fn2);
    emp2.getFirstname();



    System.out.println("Enter the 2 employee last name: ");
    String ln2;
    ln2 = input.nextLine();
    emp2.setLastname(ln2);
    emp2.getLastname();


    System.out.println("Enter the 2 employee yearly salary: ");
    double sl2;
    sl2 = input.nextDouble();
    emp2.setSalary(sl2);
    emp2.getSalary();

    System.out.printf("%s %s's yearly salary before the raise is %.2f\n", emp2.getFirstname(), emp2.getLastname(), emp2.getSalary());
```

So, when I run it, for the first employee (obj emp1) I can properly assign a first name and a last name. But when it gets to the second employee, it just prints out two times the input for the second name of employee 2, and then assigns the Last name for the second employee to the first name for the first employee and then right after that his salary

Example:

Enter the 1 employee first name: 
John

Enter the 1 employee last name: 
Doe

Enter the 1 employee yearly salary: 
100

John Doe's yearly salary before the raise is 100.00

Enter the 2 employee first name: //here I cannot type the employee2 first name

Enter the 2 employee last name: 
Miguel

Enter the 2 employee yearly salary: 
200

Miguel's yearly salary before the raise is 200.00
They receive a 10% raise .....

John Miguel's salary after the raise is: 110.00  //incorrect name

Miguel's salary after the raise is: 220.00 //correct first name

Process finished with exit code 0

Help please

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe that you aren't properly consuming the input. For example, when you use your nextDouble(), the code is leaving a /n delimeter on the first line, so nextLine() after that will only consume that while setting emp2's first name. Therefore, that leaves emp2's first name empty. A solution to this would just to have a nextLine() after the nextDouble(), so as to not leave the delimeter there.

If you're confused, you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161870/java-console-skipping-input).